# Lock down the access of AppServices to only Azure Front Door

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I would like to restrict access to my AppServices and only traffic from Azure Front Door should be accepted.
The MS documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq) explains that we should update IP restrictions and also manage 'X-Azure-FDID'. I want to focus only on IP restrictions on this question. Then i found some useful articles like [wintellect](https://www.wintellect.com/restricting-azure-app-service-access-to-azure-front-door/) and [henrihietala](https://henrihietala.fi/limit-access-to-your-azure-web-app-from-your-azure-front-door-only/) which propose incredible powershell command to do that. It seems to work but I just noticed that IP list contains more than 100 records ! It's huge don't you think ? See my screenshot [image] Is it really needed to have so much IP to allow ? The code to retrieve a filtered list of the IPv4 and IPv6 IP addresses used by Front Door is

> $addresses = ((Get-AzNetworkServiceTag -Location $location).Values | Where-Object ( { $_.Name -eq 'AzureFrontDoor.Backend' })).properties.AddressPrefixes

Because I know my Front door resource, is there any chance to reduce all these IP ??

Regards,
Terry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Web App's Restriction, just add only one rule allowing the IPv4 CIDR "147.243.0.0/16" as shown in the image.

Then, only the traffic coming from the Azure Front Door will be allowed on your Web App.
[Access Azure FD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHjcS.png)